# 'I shall be forever/eternally grateful for her kindness' or 'I will be forever/eternally grateful for her kindness'

Tags: acknowledgement

As the title suggests, I'm writing an acknowledgement and wish to thank my advisor of studies. I wish to end this acknowledgement with something to the effect:

``I shall be forever/eternally grateful for her kindness''

or

``I will be forever/eternally grateful for her kindness''

However, I'm unsure which of these two is 'more proper' to use. I would be grateful for some advice. Thanks

Comment: This is a better question for one of the English language sites, if it's not answered there already. https://ell.stackexchange.com or https://english.stackexchange.com

Comment: All references to time seem to overshoot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is pretty strong advice [here](https://grammarist.com/usage/shall-vs-will/). Use "will" to avoid any hint of "irony".

Who knew?

Comment: I'd say "eternally grateful" has enough irony by itself.

Comment: @user151413, don't be so cynical. And, the wording wasn't mine. And, some advisors have earned it.

Comment: I didn't say that. But to me, both formulations (at least with "eternally") sound equally exaggerated.

Comment: I see my question has sparked much controversy… I tend to agree with @Buffy in that my advisor of studies has indeed earned the ``exaggerated’’ gratitude. Thus, I have decided to go with ‘I will be forever grateful for her kindness…’. Thanks to those that took the time to answer/make suggestions.